# Express.js form request stuck on pending

Tags: javascript, forms, express, post, request

I am trying to post to express from a form, every time I try, no matter what, the post request gets stuck on pending.

[image: stuck on pending.]

this is my express code dumbed down;

```
this.router.get('/register', this.rateLimit(1000 * 60, 25), async (req, res) => {
            res.render('register');
        });

        this.router.post('/test', (res, req) => {
            res.send('it worked')
        })
```

Now, my morgan logger says that it has got the post request: `Fri 19:24:16 [INFO] 127.0.0.1 [POST] /user/test`

But it never reaches the `this.router.post` area. By logging and ect. I can provide more code if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Similar story here, no resolution for that for weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **next()** like below:

```
 this.router.get('/register', this.rateLimit(1000 * 60, 25), async (req, res,next) => {
        res.render('register');
        next();
    });

    this.router.post('/test', (req,res,next) => {
        res.send('it worked');
        next();

    })
```

You should you use next() to pass control to the next middleware function.
Please refer to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Comment: `
ReferenceError: next is not defined
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\api\src\Routes\User.js:46:4
`

Comment: @JackCrispy I have updated the code snippet.next should be included in the callback function.

Comment: Hey. I tried putting next in register and it said some stuff about setting headers after a request is sent, so i removed them, but in the /test one, it didn't change anything, it still is stuck on pending.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you're getting a 500 error. Is your server running properly? Would be nice to get a view of that error.

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer hey?

Comment: Yeah it's running properly, there is no error. The request is stuck on pending.

Comment: @JackCrispy - Your own screen shot shows a 500 error coming back from `/register`.  That is not "running properly".

Comment: That's an error i was fixing. has nothing to do with this, ignore it. The request to the /test url is stuck on pending, register has nothing to do.